# Выделение активного дочернего элемента CSS

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, имеет аккардион на css. Но нужно выделять цветом активную ссылку.

Я попробовал через active+класс, что показано в примере. Но это срабатывает лишь при нажатии. Как сделать так, чтобы постоянно подсвечивалось определенным цветом?

```css
[id^=acc] {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
}

[id^=acc]:target {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 0.2s;
}
.subparagraph:active {
    color:#f00 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a href="#acc1">Heading 1</a>
    <ul id="acc1">
      <li class="subparagraph"><a href="#">content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#acc2">Heading 2</a>
    <ul id="acc2">
      <li class="subparagraph" ><a href="#">content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#acc3">Heading 3</a>
    <ul id="acc3">
      <li class="subparagraph"><a href="#">content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть для этого псевдоселектор `:focus` (по секрету для аккордеонов используют тег dd, dl)

UPD добавил пример на Js

```js
var subparagraph = document.querySelectorAll('.subparagraph a')
for (var i = 0; i < subparagraph.length; i++) {
  subparagraph[i].onclick = function(evt){
    for (var j = 0; j < subparagraph.length; j++) {
     subparagraph[j].style.color = "blue";
    }
     evt.target.style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
[id^=acc] {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
}

[id^=acc]:target {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a href="#acc1">Heading 1</a>
    <ul id="acc1">
      <li class="subparagraph"><a href="#">content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#acc2">Heading 2</a>
    <ul id="acc2">
      <li class="subparagraph" ><a href="#">content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#acc3">Heading 3</a>
    <ul id="acc3">
      <li class="subparagraph"><a href="#">content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: к сожалению, после перехода по ссылке фокус теряется

Comment: А `:visited` пробовали ?

Comment: Могу сделать на JS

Comment: @Duoxx как я понял. Постоянного подсвечивания цветом на css не выйдет? 
Если не сложно. Можешь простенький js накидать для этого?)

Comment: Ок, а с jquery или нет?

Comment: Обновил пример.